# How to substitute a list in python/mysql

Tags: python, mysql

This is using the python mysql.connector from MySQL.

I'm wanting to write an update query where id is in a list, e.g.

```
UPDATE tbl SET thing=1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

If I was placeholding single elements, I would write:

```
qry = ("UPDATE tbl SET thing=1 WHERE id=%s")
cur.execute (qry,(var,))
```

I don't know how long my list is each time so I can't go with `%s, %s, %s ...n` etc.  I could `",".join(list)` and just write a query with a raw string each time but feels like a hack.

Is there a preferred way to do something like this?  This might be a wider question about using placeholders in queries in general but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you query requires `IN` then use `IN`, there is no need to replace it with `=` for example:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+-------+
| id   | thing |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     5 |
|    2 |     5 |
|    3 |     5 |
|    4 |     5 |
|    5 |     5 |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> my_ids
[1, 3, 5]
>>> sql
'UPDATE foo SET thing=1 WHERE id IN %s'
>>> cur.execute(sql, (my_ids,))
3L
>>> conn.commit()
```

Then all rows will be updated:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+-------+
| id   | thing |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     1 |
|    2 |     5 |
|    3 |     1 |
|    4 |     5 |
|    5 |     1 |
+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: "Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type"